# Using cleanco on dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a script to clean company names using cleanco module in Python.

cleanco has an example which is as follows:

```
business_name = "Some Big Pharma, LLC"
x = cleanco(business_name)
x.clean_name()
```

which results in "Some Big Pharma".

I am trying to do the same for a column in a pandas data frame.

So far my code is:

```
#Importing Packages

import pandas as pd
from cleanco import cleanco

#Create a data frame for testing purposes

columns = ['emp'] #Define column names
new_col = ['emp2'] #Define column names for second dataframe


df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns) #Create an empty data frame
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=new_col)


df['emp'] = ['ABC, Inc.', 'XYZ LTD']#populate the data frame with dummy values

df["emp"] = [x.strip().replace('.','').replace('''''', '').replace('-', '').replace(',','') for x in df['emp'].str.lower()]

df2['emp2'] = df['emp'].apply(cleanco,1)

df['emp'].apply(cleanco.clean_name()) #This is where the error lies
```

I am having trouble calling the *clean_name* function.

my first data frame:

0 ABC, Inc.

1 XYZ LTD

I want df2 to look like:

0 abc

1 xyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a lambda function to pull the "clean" name from the newly created column.

Try this:

```
df2['emp3'] = df2['emp2'].apply(lambda x: x.clean_name())
```